# Handle 404 error on audio tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 application with typscript. I have an audio tag, which receives its file as `@Input`, i want to generate an exception when the file does not exist in the path:

The html is:

```
<div>
    <audio  controls autoplay  id="audio" (error)="audioError()">
      <!--source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"-->
      <source [src]="fileToPlay" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

The component is:

```
export class PlayComponent implements OnChanges  {

  @Input() fileToPlay:string;

    audioError(){
 console.log('out of range');
 }

}
```

I tried to use `onerror` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

use `(error)` instead of `onerror`(surround event with paranthesis).

```
<audio  controls autoplay  id="audio" (error)="audioError()">
  <!--source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"-->
  <source [src]="fileToPlay" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I updated my question. @Pankaj Parkar